# Cant access eloquent model in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with my code. I am creating an administrator registration and I can't access my model using eloquent. I have my customer user registration and I followed the same format but I can't do it in my admin part.

Here's my code:

Routes

```
Route::model('administrator','Administrator');

Route::get('/flaxadmin', 'AdministratorsController@index');
Route::get('/admin_login', 'AdministratorsController@login');
Route::get('/admin_register', 'AdministratorsController@register');
Route::get('/admin_dashboard', 'AdministratorsController@dashboard');

Route::post('/admin_handle_register', function()
    {

        $rules = array(
            'admin_username'    =>  'required|min:5|max:15',
            'admin_lastname'    =>  'required|min:2|max:20',
            'admin_firstname'   =>  'required|max:20',
            'admin_password'    =>  'required|min:8|max:16',
            'admin_cpassword'   =>  'required|same:admin_password'
        );

        $validate_admin_register = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

        if($validate_admin_register->fails()) {

            $messages = $validate_admin_register->messages();

            return Redirect::to('admin_register')->withErrors($messages)->withInput(Input::except('password','cpassword'));

        } else {

            $admin = new Administrator;

            $admin->username    = Input::get('username');
            $admin->lastname    = Input::get('lastname');
            $admin->firstname   = Input::get('firstname');
            $admin->password    = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
            $admin->save();

            Session::flash('success_notification','Success: The admin account has been successfully created!');
            return Redirect::action('AdministratorsController@index');

        }

    });
```

My model

```
<?php

class Admninistrator extends Eloquent {

}

?>
```

Here's my error message

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_ERROR) 
Class 'Administrator' not found
```

I don't know where's my error. can you help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class name is `Admninistrator` Not `Administrator`

change these line

```
class Admninistrator extends Eloquent {

}
```

To this line

```
class Administrator extends Eloquent {

}
```

Comment: Ouch.. is that all? haha Im so stupid. Thanks for the response. :)

Comment: @Jerielle dear you are not stupid. i am stupid too. But thats was obivious through your error message thats why i was able to solve it. me to stupid so shake hand will be nice

Comment: haha i have a difficulty in my keyboard.. I need to buy a new keyboard.. Next time I will double check the code before posting here.. :)